# How to select columns whose elements are all 0 in R?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, tidyverse

I am struggling to select all columns whose elements are all 0. Here is a simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,0,1,0),B=c(0,0,0,0),C=c(1,1,0,0),D=c(0,0,0,0))
df
  A B C D
1 1 0 1 0
2 0 0 1 0
3 1 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
```

I want to select Columns B and D. I know the `dplyr::select`allows to select by colnames. But how to select columns by their values? Something like `select(across(everything(),~.x==0))`. But the `across()` cannot be used in `select()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `where` inside the `select` statement to find the columns that have a sum of 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(where(~sum(.) == 0))
```

Or you could use `colSums` in base R:

```
df[,colSums(df) == 0]
```

**Output**

```
  B D
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
```